# Using a text file to create a login system

Tags: python, python-3.x

**strong text**I am using a text file to create a logging system for a simple text-based game on python 3.7:

```
#puts information from a text file into a list so it can be compared to users inputs
logininfo = []
for line in open('user input.txt'):
    separator = ':'
    line = line.split(separator)
    for value in line:
        logininfo.append(value)
#To see whats inside the list of 'logininfo'        
print (logininfo)
#To separate it in the output screen, makes it easier too read
print("##########################")

username = str(input("Please enter your username: "))
password = str(input("Please enter your password: "))

#variable 'z' can be named anything
z = 0
#loops until it finds username in the database or goes through each data
while z < len(logininfo):
  if username == str(logininfo[z]):
    print ("Username exist")
    #variable 'g' can be named anything or could: z = z+1
    #one index higher than the usernames index (in the database) is always the corresponding password
    g = z + 1
    #puts data in new variable so we can remove the gaps it comes with it
    passwordshouldequal = str(logininfo[g])
    #Removes any spaces
    passwordshouldequal.replace(" ", "")
    #Checks information in the variable
    print (passwordshouldequal)
    if password == passwordshouldequal:
      print("Entered")
      exit()
    else:
      print ("password is wrong")
      #so it does not exit the loop
      exit()
  z = z + 1

#if the username does not exist 
print ("Error or username does not exist")
```

The expected result is to end with 'Entered'.The actual result ended with 'password is wrong'. Can anyone please help me, thank you!

**Edit**: People were asking what was inside my "user inputs' text file so I took a pic of the text file and the output screen. And also thank you, I appreciate all of your guys help! Picture of 'user inputs' (registered users' username and password) and output screen:https://www.reddit.com/user/PlayableWolf/comments/eliq7y/stack_overflow/?utm_medium=android_app&utm_source=share

**Edit #2**: removed the else bit at the end as I forgot to remove beforehand (when I was tinkering with the code)

**Edit #3**: Special thank you to **Michael Richardson** who helped me solve my problem. Also a special thank you to **nakE** who went beyond and helped me improve my code. Finally thank you to all who commented on my question, every one of your comments has been read and been taken to heart. So, once again, thank you ever one!

Comment: Can you add a public link to your file 'user input.txt'?

Comment: What is the problem exactly, and for who is the `else` condition at the end ? Also, you can remove the spaces by using the `strip` method.

Comment: you are incrementing `z` by 1 and it should be 2 as you are storing pairs of username+password

Comment: You are not closing the file at the end.

Comment: There are multiple issues with this code, I strongly recommend learning more Python, and programming in general. Stack Overflow is a reference, not a complete guide or tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `passwordshouldequal.replace(" ", "")` is not being stored. You need to replace that line with:

```
passwordshouldequal = passwordshouldequal.replace(" ", "")
```

This might still fail as the last username/password could contain a new line character (\n). I would replace it with the following:

```
passwordshouldequal = passwordshouldequal.replace(" ", "").replace("\n", "")
```

or a cleaner way:

```
passwordshouldequal = passwordshouldequal.strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend to open the file with `with`, so the file will closed automatically, you are not closing the file at the end. also an easier way to remove the spaces from the string, is the use the `strip` method, there are 3 types of the `strip` method, one is removing from the left side (`lstrip`) and one from the right side (`rstrip`), the regular one is the removing from both sides (`strip`).

```
with open('user input.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        # perform things with the file
        # the file will closed automatically
```

One more thing, for who is the `else` condition at the end ? and your `if` condition is not even in the correct line.

you should double check your code, take a break to think over what you want to achieve, this isn't it.